# Kendo Grid skips a page when using pager

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Currently I have a kendo grid pager at the bottom that works fine. I duplicated the pager so that it is on top and now if I use the functionality of the top pager, it is skipping a page when I hit next and back and I can't seem to figure out how it is doing that. Has anyone else experienced this?

```
// This is where we added the same toolbar thats on the bottom of the grid to the top
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var wrapper = $('<div class="k-pager-wrap pagerTop"/>').insertBefore(grid.element.children(".k-grid-header"));
wrapper.kendoPager($.extend({}, grid.options.pageable, { dataSource: grid.dataSource }));
grid.element.height("").find(".pagerTop").css("border-width", "0 0 1px 0");
```

Comment: I was trying to reproduce it but without success: http://dojo.telerik.com/oZEGa . My guess is that kedno binds events for your top headers two times. Check please is `change` event fires 2 times for your top pager.

Comment: how do i check to see if the change event is firing more than once?

Comment: `wrapper.kendoPager($.extend({}, grid.options.pageable, { dataSource: grid.dataSource, change: function(){console.log('event fired');} }));` and hit F12 to see developement tools console.

Comment: ok that worked, but looks like it only fired once, I was thinking that may have been the problem as well, I just couldn't figure out how to tell if it was. If I were to refresh the grid without refreshing the page, it will go back to normal moving up and back 1. Strange that it only works if the grid is loaded twice. Im trying to find a better way to make it work